# Firebase: updatePassword() não funciona

Tags: firebase, react-native

Estou tentando realizar um sistema de redefinição de senha em meu projeto React Native com Firebase porém não funciona de maneira alguma.

O state do email é exibido normal no Alert, porém a senha retorna undefined.

```
update = async() => {
    const password = this.state;

    if(password != ""){

        auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                user.updatePassword(password.toString()).then(function() {
                    Alert.alert(`${user.email} - ${user.password}`);
                  }).catch(function(error) {
                    Alert.alert(error);
                  });
            } else {
                //Alert.alert("deslogado");   
            }
        });
    }

    else{
        this.setState({error: "Campo Vazio!"});
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

partindo do pressuposto que irá executar sua função quando o usuário esteja logado:

não use `onAuthStateChanged()` para recuperar o usuário pois este somente recupera o usuário quando há eventos de login, logout e troca do token (sendo assim não apresentará valor). simplesmente use `auth().currentUser`.

```
update = async() => {
    const password = this.state;
    const user = auth().currentUser;
    if (password != "") {
      user.updatePassword(password).then(function() {
         Alert.alert(`Atualizado senha: ${user.email} - ${password}`);
      }).catch(function(error) {
         Alert.alert(`ocorreu um erro: ${error}`);   
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({error: "Campo Vazio!"});
    }
}
```

Lembre-se que algumas ações que apresentam riscos à segurança, como excluir uma conta, definir um endereço de e-mail principal e alterar uma senha, exigem que o usuário tenha feito login recentemente. Se você realizar uma dessas ações e o usuário tiver feito login há muito tempo, a ação falhará e gerará um erro. Quando isso acontecer, autentique o usuário novamente gerando novas credenciais de login e transmitindo-as para `reauthenticateWithCredential()`

para usar `reauthenticateWithCredential()`:

```
const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential).then(function() {
  // Usuário reautenticado
  // agora você pode user.updatePassword() sem precupapções
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Um erro ocorreu.
})
```